# How do I get my program (Lottery game) to check the tips again?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I am trying to write a lottery program (based on a hungarian game, 5 numbers from 1 to 90), it works almost fine, the first time i give it faulty numbers (more than 90 or 0) it tells me that I did wrong. But the second time it doesn't. It keeps on executing the game with the invalid numbers. What were your tips, and what would you Guys do differently?

Thank you for your time.

The code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Lottery {

static int hits = 0;
Integer[] tippek = new Integer[5];
Random rand = new Random();
ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static Lottery lot = new Lottery();

public static void main (String[] args){

    lot.wnums();
    lot.tipread();
    lot.tipcheck();
    lot.wincheck();
    lot.result();

}



public void wnums () {
        // GENERATING THE WINNER NUMBERS
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; set.size() < 5; i++){
            int x = rand.nextInt(90) + 1;
            set.add(x);
        }
        nums.addAll(set);

    }

public void tipread (){
    // READING THE TIPS
    System.out.println("Please write 5 different number from 1 to 90.");
    try{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    tippek[0] = scan.nextInt();
    tippek[1] = scan.nextInt();
    tippek[2] = scan.nextInt();
    tippek[3] = scan.nextInt();
    tippek[4] = scan.nextInt();
    }catch (InputMismatchException ex){
        System.out.println("Error.");
    }
}

public void tipcheck() {

    int fault = 0;

    List<Integer> tips = Arrays.asList(tippek);
    try{
    for(int tipp : tippek){
        System.out.println(tipp);
        if(tipp == 0 || tipp > 90){
            fault++;
        }
    }
    if(fault == 1){
        System.out.println("One of your tips is invalid ");
        System.out.println("Write other numbers");
        lot.tipread();
    }
    if(fault > 1){
        System.out.println(fault + " of your tips are invalid ");
        System.out.println("Write other numbers");
        lot.tipread();
    }

    for(int tipp : tips){
        for(int i = 0; i < tips.size(); i++){
            if(tips.indexOf(tips.get(i)) != tips.lastIndexOf(tips.get(i))){
                System.out.println("You can write a number only once");
                lot.tipread();
            }
        }
    }

    }catch (NullPointerException ex){
        System.out.println("Error.");
    }



}

public void wincheck () {
    // CHECKING THE TIPS
    try{
    for(int tipp : tippek){
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if(nums.get(i) == tipp){
                hits++;
            }
        }
    }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}

public void result() {
    try{
    Arrays.sort(tippek);
    Collections.sort(nums);
    String tippeksor = Arrays.toString(tippek); 
    System.out.println("Your tips in ascending order: " + tippeksor);
    System.out.println("You have " + hits + " hits.");
    System.out.println("The winning numbers are: " + nums);

    }catch(Exception ex){
        lot.tipread();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: `tipcheck` calls `tipread` on invalid numbers but doesn't `tipcheck` again. Solution: Let `tipcheck` return a boolean if all is ok. Use a while-loop to read and then check until `tipcheck` is happy.

Answer (score 1):

Include `lot.tipcheck()` as the last statement inside `tipread()`:

```
public void tipread (){
    // READING THE TIPS
    System.out.println("Please write 5 different number from 1 to 90.");
    try{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    tippek[0] = scan.nextInt();
    tippek[1] = scan.nextInt();
    tippek[2] = scan.nextInt();
    tippek[3] = scan.nextInt();
    tippek[4] = scan.nextInt();

    lot.tipcheck();
    }catch (InputMismatchException ex){
        System.out.println("Error.");
    }
}
```

so to ensure that every time the user inputs valid numbers they will be checked.  
Other modifications:  
remove `lot.tipcheck();` from `main()`  
After every `lot.tipread();` in `tipcheck()` add a `return;`

Answer (score 1):

instead of calling `tipread` directly from `tipcheck`
`tipcheck` returns `true` if everything is ok, `false` otherwise
and use `do-while` in main.

```
public static void main (String[] args){
   lot.wnums();
   do {
     lot.tipread();
    } while(!lot.tipcheck());
   lot.wincheck();
  lot.result();
}
```

and

```
public boolean tipcheck() {
int fault = 0;

List<Integer> tips = Arrays.asList(tippek);
try{
  for(int tipp : tippek){
    System.out.println(tipp);
    if(tipp < 1 || tipp > 90){
      fault++;
    }
  }
  if(fault == 1){
    System.out.println("One of your tips is invalid ");
    System.out.println("Write other numbers");
    // lot.tipread();
    return false;
  }
  if(fault > 1){
    System.out.println(fault + " of your tips are invalid ");
    System.out.println("Write other numbers");
    // lot.tipread();
    return false;
  }

  for(int tipp : tips){
    for(int i = 0; i < tips.size(); i++){
      if(tips.indexOf(tips.get(i)) != tips.lastIndexOf(tips.get(i))){
        System.out.println("You can write a number only once");
        // lot.tipread();
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

}catch (NullPointerException ex){
  System.out.println("Error.");
  return false;
}
return true;
}
```

like this.